# Adding product to shopping cart via Magento API results in a 0 price

Tags: api, magento

I'm trying to programmatically create an order and invoice in Magento but whenever I add products to the shopping cart, the price of each product is set to 0, thus resulting in a NULL total.

I also tried the moveToCustomerQuote method but that throws a Magento Fault saying that the customer quote (shoppingcart ID) doesn't exist.

Here's my code

```
$cart           = $magi->execute("cart.create");
$add_customer   = $magi->execute("cart_customer.set",array($cart,$customer));

$products   = array(array(
                "product_id"    => 167,
                "qty"           => 50
              ));

$add_product    = $magi->execute("cart_product.add",array($cart,$products));
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is there another step I should take to get the product to list the price properly?